# How to duplicate characters in a string (in place) with python?

Tags: python, string

I apologize if this question appears worded poorly; I've supplied an input and desired output below to illustrate the effect I want to produce

```py
inpt = 'aabbaa'
duplicate_range = [2,4]

some_func(inpt, duplicate_range)
>>>>'aabbbbaa'
```

Essentially, I want to duplicate the `bb` found in my `inpt` string, such that the duplication occurs immediately following the original occurrence.

Comment: Python strings are inmutable, so `inplace` will not be possible.

Comment: if the input string was `'abcdef'` would you want the output to be `'abcdcdef'` or `'abccddef'`?

Comment: @SimonCrane great question - given the same duplicate range of elements `[2:4]`, correspond to the substring `'cd'`, I would expect an output of `'abcdCDef'` I've capitalized the second occurence solely to draw attention to it (not because I want it capitalized in the actual output).

Comment: What did you try and why does it not work? I want X is not really a good question, even if you supply input and output :o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```py
inpt = 'aabbaa'
duplicate_range = [2,4]


def some_func(inpt, duplicate_range):
    start = duplicate_range[0]
    end = duplicate_range[1]
    return inpt[:start] + 2*inpt[start:end] + inpt[end:]

print(some_func(inpt, duplicate_range))

>>> 'aabbbbaa'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could build a `slice` from the list of ranges, and build a new string by slicing the initial string and adding the the substrings to be duplicated

```
inpt = 'aabbaa'
duplicate_range = [2,4]
```

---

```
s = slice(*duplicate_range)
inpt[:s.start] + inpt[s]*2 + inpt[s.stop:]
# 'aabbbbaa'
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you need:

```
inpt = 'aabbaa'
duplicate_range = [2,4]

def some_func(x, rng):
  substr = x[rng[0]:rng[1]]
  x = x[:rng[0]]+substr*2+x[rng[1]:]
  return x

print(some_func(inpt, duplicate_range))
```

Answer (score 1):

One simple and elegant way I could think of is this:

```
def some_func(inpt,a,b):
     return inpt[:a] + inpt[a:b]*2 + inpt[b:]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to accept it as separate values:

```py
def duplicate_chars(original, start=0, end=-1):
    return original[:start] + original[start:end]*2 + original[end:]

print(duplicate_chars("aabbaa", 2, 4))  # "aabbbbaa"
```

---

You could also change the input to be a slice if you prefer to give only one extra parameter instead of two:

```py
def duplicate_chars(original, bounds):
    return original[:bounds.start] + original[bounds]*2 + original[bounds.stop:]

print(duplicate_chars("aabbaa", slice(2,4)))  # "aabbbbaa"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
def duplicate_part(mystr, duplicate_range):
    start, end = duplicate_range
    part = mystr[start:end] * 2
    new_str = mystr[:start] + part + mystr[end:]
    return new_str

mystr = 'aabbaa'
duplicate_range = [2,4]

duplicate_part(mystr, duplicate_range)
# 'aabbbbaa'
```

Answer (score 0):

## Using str.replace()

### One line solution:

```py
inpt = 'aabbaa'
d_r = [2,4]  # duplicated_range (to save space)


inpt = inpt[:d_r[0]] + inpt[d_r[0]:d_r[1]].replace(inpt[d_r[0]:d_r[1]], inpt[d_r[0]:d_r[1]]*2) + inpt[d_r[1]:]

print(inpt)
```

Which Yields:

`'aabbbbaa'`

### Using it in a function:

```py
def some_func(inpt, d_r):
    return inpt[:d_r[0]] + inpt[d_r[0]:d_r[1]].replace(inpt[d_r[0]:d_r[1]], inpt[d_r[0]:d_r[1]]*2) + inpt[d_r[1]:]

print(some_func(inpt, d_r))
```

Which Yields:

`'aabbbbaa'`